# Using the REST api to retrieve multiple objects with a single request

Tags: soql, rest-api, data-synchronization

I'm trying to figure out how to best retrieve all of the `ids` returned by calling `getUpdated`.  I'm using the REST API and I don't see anyway of retrieving a list of ids with a single request.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=intro_usage_rest_resources.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fintro_usage_rest_resources.htm|SkinName=webhelp

I've considered execution a SOQL query with a condition like `Id in ids[]` but the ids array is often to large and the request fails.

What is the most efficient way using the REST API to retrieve all updated ids?

Comment: `getUpdated` will return up to 200,000 IDs for a given object within a given time range. So, reduce the time range per each call to avoid hitting the limit

Comment: the question is not about `getUpdated`, I'm wondering how do I get the instances given the IDs that come back from `getUpdated`. I was hoping there was a REST api that let me take the array of IDs from `getUpdated` and retrieve all of them.  But I'm not seeing it.

Comment: did u try using the Bulk APIs which is also REST based... [Reference](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/)    [Samples](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough.htm)

Comment: I'm not aware of such REST service; only SOQL will get 2+ objects and it will be limited by the size of the query string.  If you look at the SOAP API https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_guidelines_datareplication.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_guidelines_datareplication.htm|SkinName=webhelp you can use retrieve() and pass in the list of IDs and get objects back in one call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am reasonably certain the REST API allows for [only one object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/resources_sobject_retrieve.htm) per retrieve (?)

The SOAP API however allows you to retrieve [up to 2000 IDs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_retrieve.htm) per API call!

If you're doing a lot of data loading, the Bulk API may be a better fit for your app. For most other reasonably complex client apps, there may still be enough API differences that you'll benefit from using both the REST and SOAP APIs.